# how to parse field with same name using SAXParser

Tags: saxparser

i have following xml file:

```
<package>
  <reader>
    <id>r1007</id>
    <name>Robert</name>
    <email>robert@yahoo.com</email>
  </reader>
  <writer>
    <id>w1920</id>
    <name>Young</name>
    <email>young@hotmail.com</email>
  </writer>
</package>
```

both 'reader' and 'writer' have fields as 'id', 'name' and 'email', how can i differentiate them using SAXParser since SAXParser only tell 'startElement' and 'endElement'. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a stack of the parents of the element you are in.

Comment: does SAXParser provide any stack or i have to have my own stack?

Comment: You have to do it all yourself

Comment: got it, i use flag instead, for simple structure it works fine.